# Eclipse cannot execute cc1 despite its appearance in the folder

Tags: c, linux, stm32f4discovery

I have problem when I try to build project for STM32F4 in eclipse on linux system. The error says: `arm-none-eabi-gcc: error trying to exec '/home/abcd/.p2/pool/plugins/fr.ac6.mcu.externaltools.arm-none.linux64_1.13.1.201703061524/tools/compiler/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/cc1': execv: No such file or directory`. I have found the file under mentioned directory and it exists. I also tried to reinstall and update packages related to gcc and cc1 as mentioned on stackoverflow, but I still cannot build the project. I am feeling helpless, so I will be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: You're never supposed to run `cc1` directly unless you are working on gcc itself.  Where is the `gcc` executable?  Please also show us the _complete and unedited_ text of __all__ of the error messages; you appear to have chopped off the beginning.  Every word in a Unix-style error message is significant.

Comment: Sorry for inconvinience, I edited message adding complete error. gcc seems to be located in: /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: Is it possible that the `cc1` executable is a 32-bit executable, but your system doesn't have 32-bit support libraries installed?  Or maybe it's an LSB-compiled executable, but the system doesn't have LSB support?  That can lead to this situation where it seems it's reporting a file doesn't exist when it does exist - what it's actually reporting is that it can't find the dynamic linker.

Comment: You could try `file /home/abcd/.../cc1` and `readelf -a /home/abcd/.../cc1 | grep interpreter` to see what the executable format is and what dynamic linker it requires.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing Daniel did.  Also, lemme decode the error message a little: Eclipse is successfully running the compiler "driver" program that it's supposed to run (`arm-none-eabi-gcc`) and _that_ program is attempting to run a plausibly named internal binary (`.../arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/cc1`)  and getting a low-level failure.  This is  an installation problem, but I don't think it's the _compiler_ that is mis-installed; more likely support libraries, as Daniel says.

Comment: Of course, it's slightly suspicious that `arm-none-eabi-gcc` runs but its `cc1` doesn't - I would expect them to have been compiled the same way.  Is it possible there's some sort of mismatch between the two?

Comment: What does `which arm-none-eabi-gcc` print?  Please also try Daniel's suggestions regarding `file` and `readelf`.

Comment: What happens if you run the compiler outside of Eclipse? Or if you run cc1 directly?

Comment: `file` output: `/home/abcd/.p2/pool/plugins/fr.ac6.mcu.externaltools.arm-none.linux64_1.13.1.201703061524/tools/compiler/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/cc1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped`, `readelf` output: `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]`, `which` output: `/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc`

Comment: I also get error `Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/subdir.mk:63: recipe for target 'Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/stm32f4xx_hal.o' failed
make: *** [Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/stm32f4xx_hal.o] Error 1` after error mentioned above, which might be related.

Comment: Hmm.  What does `ls -l /lib/ld-linux*` print?  (Please edit this into your question so that line breaks are preserved.)

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/lib/ld-linux*': No such file or directory` - I installed the file after that and now it seems to build right, thank you!